# Loop prints output twice after initial loop

Tags: java

Okay so this has been bugging me right into the early hours of the morning.

```
static void play(int[][] puzzle) {
    int var1 = 10;
    int var2 = 2;
    int[][] original = new int[N][N]; 
    reset(puzzle);
    original(original);
    int[][] arroriginal = original;
    scramble(puzzle);
    int[][] currentarr = puzzle;
    @SuppressWarnings("resource")
    Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("---- Instructions ----");
    System.out.println("To complete the puzzle, order the numbers in numerical order using the commands");
    
    
    print(currentarr);
    
    while (currentarr!=original){
        int b=0;
        System.out.println("");
        System.out.println("For row enter 'r'");
        System.out.println("For Column enter 'c'");
        System.out.println("");
        
        
        String input = s.nextLine().trim();
        
        if (input.equals("r")) {
            System.out.println("What row?");
            int rows = s.nextInt();
            
            rotateRow(currentarr,rows);
            print(currentarr);
            b++;
        }
        else if (input.equals("c")) {
            System.out.println("What column?");
            int column = s.nextInt();
            
            rotateColumn(currentarr,column);
            print(currentarr);
            b++;
        }
        if (b == 0){
            System.out.println("Invalid input");
            }
        boolean truefalse = Arrays.equals(arroriginal, currentarr);
        if (truefalse == true){
            System.out.println("Congratulations");
            break;
      
            
        }
    
            
                    }
                }
```

This is my code - when ran this is what I get:

```
 ### Testing puzzle game play####
 ---- Instructions ----
To complete the puzzle, order the numbers in numerical order using the       commands
   0   1   2   3
   7   4   5   6
  11   8   9  10
  12  13  14  15


For row enter 'r'
For Column enter 'c'

r
What row?
1
   0   1   2   3
   6   7   4   5
  11   8   9  10
  12  13  14  15


For row enter 'r'
For Column enter 'c'

Invalid input

For row enter 'r'
For Column enter 'c'
```

For some reason I get 'invalid input' when I shouldnt be and I also get a repeat of 'For row enter 'r', for column enter 'c'.

My assignment is due in 8 hours and I have literally tried everything, if you manage to fix this you must be a wizard of all things java haha.

Comment: There is still an unread newline token after you call `s.nextInt()`. Try calling `s.nextLine()` after you scan an integer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is with the `s.nextInt()` command it only reads the int value. So when you continue reading with `s.nextLine()` you get the "\n" Enter key. So to skip this you have to add the `s.nextLine()`. Hope this should be clear now.

Try something like that:

```
System.out.print("Insert a number: ");
int number = input.nextInt();

input.nextLine(); // This line you have to add (It consumes the \n character)

System.out.print("Text1: ");
String text1 = input.nextLine();

System.out.print("Text2: ");
String text2 = input.nextLine();
```

Comment: This gives me the error 'The method nextLine() is undefined for the type String' How do you work around this? Thanks for your help